# Existe algum risco em usar "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0"?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, segurança

De acordo com o que eu li em algum lugar, o `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`:

> ... especifica se deve ou não verificar restrições de chave estrangeira para tabelas InnoDB.

Ou seja, se o cara quer desabilitar a checagem de chaves estrangeiras, ele faz:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Eu sei que é comum usar esse comando em caso de dumps para fazer migração de banco, backups e coisas do tipo... Mas fico me perguntando se algo que pode desabilitar a checagem de chaves estrangeiras pode ser ou não nocivo para uma aplicação.

Tenho as seguintes perguntas:

- Em que tipos de cenários seria válido ou não usar `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` com o valor `0`?
- `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` é algo a ser considerado em restringir em ambiente de produção? É algo que pode causar algum tipo de incosistência na minha aplicação/banco de dados?
- Se for possível desabilitar a modificação em `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`, como é o procedimento?

Comment: Uma analogia. A porta da sua casa tem uma tranca , deixar a porta aberta no dia da mudança trás algum risco !? Não seria mais seguro trancar e  esperar o pessoal do caminhão tocar a campainha a cada peça que tragam !?

Comment: Pessoalmente, o cenário que enxergo para usar isto é o do servidor que ainda não esta em produção, ou seja, um suposto servidor que será "o novo", tecnicamente não é necessário usar no servidor de origem (até aonde eu entendo), porque geralmente é possivel fazer o backup todo fazendo "a leitura" (e dependendo do método que usará para o dump). A "falha" de segurança, ou melhor falha de integridade só realmente é possivel se você expor o novo servidor, mas não tem muito sentido para deixar algo que ainda não esta "pronto" ativo para outras pessoas né? :)

Answer (score 4):

Não diria que traria problemas para seu banco de dados, em 100% dos casos, garantindo-se você mesmo que isto não trará prejuízo futuramente. Eu utilizo essa funcionalidade somente para recuperação de backups, mas jamais durante a execução de uma query pela Aplicação, pois desativa-la pode facilitar ataques ou anormalidades no banco. Mas como tudo na informação, cada caso é um caso, por exemplo:

- Durante recuperação de backups muito grandes, alguns servidores possui limitação no tempo de execução do SQL, manter desabilitado pode ser mais rápido.
- Em alguns casos, o banco de dados vem desatualizado para você dar manutenção, com chaves estrangeiras entre campos que não são utilizados.
- Também tem alguns outros casos específicos, onde as tabelas são preenchidas em uma ordem aleatória, e em vez ficar gastando tempo para ordena-las, alguns preferem desativar a verificação.